# How to insert default value in SQL not null-able column when passing in data from MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, triggers

We have a SQL Server database and we also have a MS Access project linked to the tables.

In one of our tables we have a NN `Nvarchar` column with a default value of `' '`.

But when trying to insert an empty string from MS Access into that column the MS Access project will throw an error for not being able to insert a null value into SQL Server, so even if we have a default value set in SQL but I would assume that MS Access is sending in explicitly a NULL value so SQL Server will try to add a NULL ..

I would guess the easy way around it is to handle it from MS Access and fill it up as a empty string instead of NULL, but I don't have Access to that project on MS Access.

Is there any way I could handle from the SQL Server side?

Comment: What's your MS-Access SQL - why would "Access be explicitly sending a NULL" when it's you that's sending the SQL? If you leave the field out of your INSERT, it should assign the Default Value.

Comment: i'm not sure in what method its being send from  MS-Access as i don't have any control over that project , so my question is if there's any way to fix it from sql server side

Comment: If Access is sending an explicit null and you're field is setup to not allow nulls, SQL SERVER has no choice but to generate an error.  The only way around it is to allow nulls - or change it on the Access side. You could add a trigger that changes nulls to ' ' on inserts

Comment: Yeah when receiving an explicit NULL the ONLY way you could handle it from sql server would be to use an instead of trigger. This is problematic though because you are dealing with the symptom instead of the problem (Access).

Comment: thanks all !!! so if trigger will be my only solution what is my best way to handle it in SQL trigger ill need a loop that loops all columns and check if its NN and in such case if its null value it should replace it with empty string                         any sample of code how to handle it in a database trigger on all tables on all columns ?